# 6v battery low voltage cut-off circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, batteries, low-battery

I have a circuit that draw 150 ma and i use 6V/4Ah dry cell to supply. Voltage regulator of this circuit needs minimum 8V so I use boost converter to draw the battery voltage to 8 volts.This converter works up to 2 volt.

[image]
 I would like to stop this module when battery goes below 4-5 volt. I tried this circuit with converter. [image]

It worked but when i connect the converter to system the input voltage of the converter is decrease and converter is not work even battery at 6V. I would like to learn why this circuit not worked and what can i do to work this circuit for cut off the voltage under 4-5 volt.

Comment: Where exactly is your second circuit connected to the first? Where is the input and the output?

Comment: You should also tell us why you think the second circuit should cut off the voltage under 4-5 volt. (The second circuit makes no sense to me)

Comment: @Aaron second circuit is connected to input of the input of the converter. (IN+)

Comment: @StefanWyss when voltage level goes under to 2V converter stop the convert. I thought if i drop the input of the converter to 2v converter stop work so add that circuit between battery and boost converter but my thought is failed.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is to use a comparator circuit that compares a reference voltage with the battery supply voltage. If the battery supply voltage falls below the reference voltage, the comparator disconnects the load e.g. with a P-channel FET.

As for the reference, you can use a simple zener diode (which is not a good reference) or better a voltage reference (e.g. TL431). Because the comparator also needs to be powered with the battery (down to 5V), you need to use a much lower reference than 5V. So you could e.g. take a 2.5V reference and compare that with the comparator against a voltage divider with 1:1 resistor ratio from the battery.

Comment: Can i obtain 5v for reference  from battery with voltage divider or another method?

Comment: I added some thoughts on the reference

Comment: A TL431 is a nice cheap configurable voltage reference. Might not be a bad idea to mention it in this answer.